# How can I pass HoDjango views.py context data variable in ng-repeat filter

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I'm trying to use a filter in angular ng-repeat where **selectedUserId** is a context_dict variable.
my angular curlies are **{--}**

**my view.py - getting the user_id from the url**

`def profile(request, user_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['selectedUserId'] = user_id
    return render_to_response('rango/profile.html', context_dict, context)`

**My ng-repeat**

< div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter:{ userId: **selectedUserId** }: true">

```
    <h1>{{ selectedUserId }} Profile<h1>
    <h2>{- profile.userId -}</h2>
```

How can I get my **selectedUserId** to render, I tried {% **selectedUserId** %} and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've rendered {{ selectedUserId }} in your `h1` tag, so in your ng-repeat you should also use `{{ selectedUserId }}`:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles | filter:{ userId: '{{ selectedUserId }}' }: true">
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I did that all day yesterday and it didn't work. today all of a sudden it works... My problem was that I forgot to put single quotes around the {{ selectedUserID }} and the result counted as a variable for angular instead of a string. Thank you !

Comment: oh, indeed, there should have been quotes around {{ selectedUserId }}. I've edited the answer to add them as well. Best regards!